# transactions through a php website

Tags: transactions, php

how I use to users to send ethereum transactions through a php website?My server is Apache. Is the Ethereum JavaScript API useful to doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what you mean by "how I use to users"? I see other people have answered, but I'm still not sure what the question is!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below steps for the same:

1) Use web3 API to communicate with blockchain.

Add [web3 CDN](https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js) to your index file.

Check [web3 documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to connect blockchain and for other actions

2) Use XMLHttpRequest() or direct AJAX call to communicate between javascript and PHP.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));  
var abi = [{<ABI>}];
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var contractInstance = myContract.at(<account address>);
val = contractInstance.<contract-method>.call();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: val
});
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Please provide me step by step detail to use it.

Answer (score 0):

可以！我现在就是这么做的 *(You can! I'm doing that now)*

```
    <?php

/**
 * Ethereum JSON-RPC interface
 *
 * See Ethereum API documentation for more information:
 * http://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/rpc.html
 */

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/json-rpc.php');

class Ethereum extends JSON_RPC
{
    private function ether_request($method, $params=array())
    {
        try 
        {
            $ret = $this->request($method, $params);
            return $ret->result;
        }
        catch(RPCException $e) 
        {
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    private function decode_hex($input)
    {
        if(substr($input, 0, 2) == '0x')
            $input = substr($input, 2);

        if(preg_match('/[a-f0-9]+/', $input))
            return hexdec($input);

        return $input;
    }

    function web3_clientVersion()
    {
```

通过api 直接调用 geth ，我有demo ，不知道怎么发给你 ^_^

*(Through the api direct call geth, I have demo, do not know how to send you ^ _ ^)*

[The documentation for JSON-RPC calls are here.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-methods)

Comment: Or you use [Ethereum-PHP](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) Library which is [documented](http://ethereum-php.org/dev/)